# Spark Streaming Kafka direct consumer consumption speed drop

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

[image: spark streaming UI]
Kafka direct consumer started to limit reads to 450 events(5 * 90 partitions) per batch (5 seconds), it was running fine for 1 or 2 days before that (about 5000 to 40000 events per batch)

I'm using spark standalone cluster (spark and spark-streaming-kafka version 1.6.1) running in AWS and using S3 bucket for checkpoint directory `StreamingContext.getOrCreate(config.sparkConfig.checkpointDir, createStreamingContext)`, there are not scheduling delays and enough disk space on each worker node.

Didn't change any Kafka client initialization parameters, pretty sure that kafka's structure hasn't changed:

```
val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> kafkaConfig.broker)
val topics = Set(kafkaConfig.topic)
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
```

Also can't understand why when direct consumer description says `The consumed offsets are by the stream itself` I still need to use checkpoint directory when creating the streaming context?

Comment: Is `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled` set to `true`?

Comment: yes, I'll try to disable it

Comment: looks like it helped

Comment: That's good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

This is usually the result of enabling backpressure via the setting `spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled` to true. Usually, when the backpressure algorithm sees that there's more data coming in then it's used to, it starts capping each batch to a rather small size until it can "stabilize" itself again. This sometimes has false positives and causes your stream to slow down the processing rate.

If you want to tweak the heuristic a little, there are some undocumented flags it is using (just make sure you know what you're doing):

```
val proportional = conf.getDouble("spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.proportional", 1.0)
val integral = conf.getDouble("spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.integral", 0.2)
val derived = conf.getDouble("spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.derived", 0.0)
val minRate = conf.getDouble("spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.minRate", 100)
```

If you want the gory details, [`PIDRateEstimator`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/rate/PIDRateEstimator.scala) is what you're looking for.